# Can I design and print report/Document from my java Application

Tags: java, document, rtf

I am developing a java desktop database application in which I have to design a report. The report can either be in MS Word or the RTF format and has a fixed layout in which some values change according to my variables. Can I design, preview and print the document from my java application?

Comment: Yes you could. Are you really asking us how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for example use the OpenOffice API:

[OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org/)

With this Java API you can build documents from scratch or open a template file to merge data into specified fields.

An example of loading a template document and merge data into user specified fields: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Example:_Fields_in_a_Template

And then you can save as different filetypes (.rtf, .doc, .pdf, ...)

---

Another solution is using:

[Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx)

> Aspose.Words for Java is an advanced class library for Java that
>   enables you to perform a great range of document processing tasks
>   directly within your Java applications.   Aspose.Words for Java
>   supports DOC, OOXML, RTF, HTML and OpenDocument formats. With
>   Aspose.Words you can generate, modify, and convert documents without
>   using Microsoft Word.

Comment: Thx I have my concerns about aspose.words... I am using java rtf editor kit and its read method is giving I/O error for no reason... I cant get an example for it as the web is ful of HTML example codes only.

Comment: I would look at JODReports or Docmosis which can save you having to learn the OpenOffice UNO API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to create these document types with Java then can i suggest you use [Apose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx):

Comment: Thx I have my concerns about aspose.words... I am using java rtf editor kit and its read method is giving I/O error for no reason...

Comment: There is a reason for everything don't give up on it so quik!